# Retrieving JSON data for Highcharts with multiple series and show it in google map infoWindow

Tags: json, dictionary, highcharts, infowindow

I would like to show multiple series of datas in a hightcharts in a google map infowindow.
It works for one serie but I would like to had a second one.

Anybody to help me? MANY THAAANKS!

Here's my code, but it didn't work.

index.php

```
        <script>
        var dataSeries=null;
        var dataRank=null;
        var selectedname="";
        $(document).ready(function() {
            var locations = 
                <?php
                $query->execute();
                echo ("[");
                while ($data = $query->fetch()) {
                    echo("[".$data['hot_webid'].",'".addslashes($data['hot_name'])."',".$data['hot_starrating'].",".$data['hot_latitude'].",".$data['hot_longitude']."],");
                }
                echo("];");
                $query->closeCursor();
                ?>;
                var iw = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
                var centerMap = new google.maps.LatLng(0,0);
                google.maps.event.addListener(iw,'domready',function(e) {       
                    // Convert date into JS UTC date
                    for (var k=0; k<dataSeries.length; k++) {
                        var d=dataSeries[k][0].split(/[- :]/);
                        dataSeries[k][0]=Date.UTC(d[0], d[1]-1, d[2], d[3], d[4], d[5]);
                    }
                    for (var k=0; k<dataRank.length; k++) {
                        var d=dataRank[k][0].split(/[- :]/);
                        dataRank[k][0]=Date.UTC(d[0], d[1]-1, d[2], d[3], d[4], d[5]);
                    }
                    dataChart = {   
                        chart: {
                            borderWidth: 2,
                            renderTo: document.getElementById('container'),
                            zoomType: 'x',
                            type:"spline",
                                lineWidth:0,
                            height:600,
                            width:500,
                            marginRight:40
                        },
                        legend: {
                            enabled: true,
                            align: 'right',
                            backgroundColor: '#FCFFC5',
                            borderColor: 'black',
                            borderWidth: 0,
                            layout: 'vertical',
                            verticalAlign: 'top',
                            y: 0,
                            x: -140,
                            shadow: false,
                            floating : true
                        },

                        rangeSelector: {
                            enabled: false
                        },
                        title: {
                            text: selectedname
                        },
                        subtitle: {
                            text: 'Prices'
                        },
                        legend: {
                            enabled: true,
                            align: 'right',
                            backgroundColor: '#FCFFC5',
                            borderColor: 'black',
                            borderWidth: 0,
                            layout: 'vertical',
                            verticalAlign: 'top',
                            y: 0,
                            x: -140,
                            shadow: false,
                            floating : true
                        },
                        xAxis: {
                            title: {
                                text: 'Date/Time'
                            }
                        },
                        yAxis: [{
                            title: {
                                text: 'Rank'
                            },
                            height: 200,
                            lineWidth: 2,
                            opposite:false
                        }, {
                            title: {
                                text: 'Price'
                            },
                            top: 300,
                            height: 200,
                            offset: 0,
                            lineWidth: 2,
                            opposite:false  
                        }],
                        navigator: {
                            enabled: false,
                        }, 
                        credits: {
                            enabled: false
                        },
                        series: [{
                            name: 'Rank',
                            color: '#4572A7',
                            type: 'spline',
                            yAxis: 0,
                            marker: { 
                                enabled:true,
                                radius:2
                            },
                            tooltip: {
                                valueDecimals : 0
                            },
                            data: dataRank,
                        },  {
                            name: 'Price',
                            color: '#89A54E',
                            type: 'spline',
                            yAxis: 1,
                            marker: { 
                                enabled:true,
                                radius:2
                            },
                            tooltip: {
                                valueSuffix: '$',
                                valueDecimals : 0
                            },
                            data: dataSeries,
                            }]
                    };
                    chart = new Highcharts.StockChart(dataChart);
                });
                var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
                    zoom: 3,
                    center: new google.maps.LatLng(0.0, 0.0),
                    mapTypeId : google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP, // Type de carte, diff�rentes valeurs possible HYBRID, ROADMAP, SATELLITE, TERRAIN
                    streetViewControl: false,
                    center: centerMap,
                    panControl: false,
                    zoomControl: true,
                    mapTypeControlOptions: {
                        style: google.maps.MapTypeControlStyle.DROPDOWN_MENU
                    },
                    zoomControlOptions: {
                        style: google.maps.ZoomControlStyle.SMALL
                    }
                });
                var inputLocation = /** @type {HTMLInputElement} */(document.getElementById('search-city'));
                // Link it to the UI element.
                // map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_LEFT].push(inputLocation);
                var autocompleteLocation = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(inputLocation);
                autocompleteLocation.bindTo('bounds', map);
                /******************** LISTENER ************************/
                google.maps.event.addListener(autocompleteLocation, 'place_changed', function() {
                    inputLocation.className = '';
                    var placeStart = autocompleteLocation.getPlace();
                    if (!placeStart.geometry) {
                        // Inform the user that the place was not found and return.
                        inputLocation.className = 'notfound';
                        return;
                    }

                    // If the place has a geometry, then present it on a map.
                    if (placeStart.geometry.viewport) {
                        map.fitBounds(placeStart.geometry.viewport);
                    } else {
                        map.setCenter(placeStart.geometry.location);
                        map.setZoom(13);  // Why 13? Because it looks good.
                    }
                    var address = '';
                    if (placeStart.address_components) {
                        address = [
                            (placeStart.address_components[0] && placeStart.address_components[0].short_name || ''),
                            (placeStart.address_components[1] && placeStart.address_components[1].short_name || ''),
                            (placeStart.address_components[2] && placeStart.address_components[2].short_name || '')
                        ].join(' ');
                    }
                });
                /******************** END LISTENER ************************/
                var marker, i;
                var markers = [];
                var contentDiv = '<center><h2>Price and Rank Evolution</h2></center><div id="container" class="info-box"></div>';
                for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {  
                    marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                        position: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][3], locations[i][4]),
                        map: map,
                        title: locations[i][1]+ " (" + locations[i][2] + " stars)"
                        });
                        markers.push(marker);
                        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (
                            function(marker, i) {
                                return function() {
                                    selectedname = locations[i][1];
                                    stopAnimation(marker);
                                    var requestR = $.ajax({
                                        url: "../ajax/map/get-rank.php",
                                        type: "POST",
                                        dataType: "json",
                                        data: { HotelId: locations[i][0] }
                                    });

                                    var requestS = $.ajax({
                                        url: "../ajax/map/get-prices.php",
                                        type: "POST",
                                        dataType: "json",
                                        data: { HotelId: locations[i][0] }
                                    });

                                    requestR.done(
                                        requestS.done(
                                            function(dataS, dataR, textStatus, jqXHR) {
                                                dataRank=dataR;
                                                dataSeries=dataS;
                                                iw.setContent(contentDiv);
                                                iw.open(map, marker);           
                                        }));
                                    requestS.fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {});
                                    return false;
                                }
                            }
                        )
                        (marker, i)
                    );
                }
                var markerCluster = new MarkerClusterer(map, markers);
                google.maps.event.addListener(iw, 'closeclick', function() {}); 
                function stopAnimation(marker) {
                    setTimeout(function () {
                        marker.setAnimation(null);
                    }, 3000);
                }
            });
    </script>
```

And my JSON php files

```
    <?php
header("Content-type: application/json");

include('../../db.php');

if (isset($_POST['HotelId'])) $res_idHotel=$_POST['HotelId'];           

$query = $bdd->prepare("SELECT res_date, res_price ".
                        "FROM exp_result ".
                        "WHERE res_idHotel = $res_idHotel ".
                        "AND res_date ".
                        //"BETWEEN DATE( DATE_SUB( NOW() , INTERVAL 7 DAY ) ) ".
                        //"AND DATE ( NOW() ) ".
                        "GROUP BY res_date ORDER BY res_date;");


$query->execute();

$data = $query->fetch();

if ($data) {
    echo "[ ";
    do {
        echo "[ \"".$data['res_date']."\", ".$data['res_price']." ]";       
        $data = $query->fetch();
        if ($data) echo ",";
    } while ($data);
    echo "]";
} else {
    echo "[]"; 
}

$query->closeCursor();
?>
```

and

```
    <?php
header("Content-type: application/json");

include('../../db.php');

if (isset($_POST['HotelId'])) $res_idHotel=$_POST['HotelId'];           

$query = $bdd->prepare("SELECT res_date, res_rank ".
                        "FROM exp_result ".
                        "WHERE res_idHotel = $res_idHotel ".
                        "AND res_date ".
                        //"BETWEEN DATE( DATE_SUB( NOW() , INTERVAL 7 DAY ) ) ".
                        //"AND DATE ( NOW() ) ".
                        "GROUP BY res_date ORDER BY res_date;");


$query->execute();

$dataR = $query->fetch();

if ($dataR) {
    echo "[ ";
    do {
        echo "[ \"".$dataR['res_date']."\", ".$dataR['res_rank']." ]";      
        $dataR = $query->fetch();
        if ($dataR) echo ",";
    } while ($dataR);
    echo "]";
} else {
    echo "[]"; 
}

$query->closeCursor();
?>
```

Comment: Quite a lot of code. What exactly doesn't work? Could you somehow recreate issue on jsFiddle?

Comment: the problme come from this part >
requestR.done(
                                        requestS.done(
                                            function(dataS, dataR, textStatus, jqXHR) {
                                                dataRank=dataR;
                                                dataSeries=dataS;
                                                iw.setContent(contentDiv);
                                                iw.open(map, marker);           
                                        }));

Comment: That doesn't tell me anything, sorry. What about jsfiddle demo with hardcoded values?

Comment: why not you make use of json_encode in php instead